# How to delete entire branch of tree starting at node X ?

Tags: neo4j

So if I have a tree of categories, how can I delete an entire branch of that tree in a single command? I tried the following

START n=node(13163) MATCH (n)-[r:SUB_CATEGORY*]->(m) WHERE m.type = "category" DELETE r,m;

Only to receive the following.. "Expression `r` yielded `Stream(Relationship[13842], ?)`. Don't know how to delete that."

Answer (score 3):

The path in your "Match" has variable length relationships, so for some node m, the r is a collection of relationships rather than a single relationship. That's why the error occurs.

You just need to return each relationship as a row, and then delete them.

```
START n=node(13163) 
MATCH path = (n)-[:SUB_CATEGORY*]->(m) 
WHERE m.type = "category" 
With m, last(relationships(path)) as r
DELETE r,m
```

In the case where there might be other relationships than the [:SUB_CATEGORY] relationship attached to the "m", the safe way is to use "with m match m-[r?]-() delete m,r" as suggested below by @Wes Freeman

Comment: +1 It's worth noting that this works because of the way paths are returned, and because the * will return a path of deepening lengths, so at some point, `last(relationships(path))` will manage to be the relationship before each child node in the tree. The reason this query might fail is that you could have other relationships coming off of those nodes, in which case you'd need to do `WITH m MATCH m-[r?]-() DELETE m,r` instead.

Comment: Good point! I haven't thought of the case where there might be other relationships attached to the m.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Works as intended.

Comment: Hey @Eric, if it works as intended, you should mark the answer as "accepted" (the green check mark next to the answer score)--only mentioning because I noticed you are new to SO. :)